# Running a Self-Developed Python Server on Docker Container

Tags: python, linux, macos, ubuntu, docker

I have this python server:

```
import SocketServer

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print 'client is connected'
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print data
        self.request.sendall('Message received!')

HOST, PORT = '0.0.0.0', 5004
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPHandler)
print 'Listening on port {}'.format(PORT)
server.serve_forever()
```

and this client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.56.101', 5004))
s.sendall('Hello my name is John')
response = s.recv(1024)
print 'Response: {}'.format(response)
```

My OS is macOS and I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a virtual machine using VirtualBox. In VirtualBox, I setup a NAT network and I gave Ubuntu this IP address: `192.168.56.101`. I put the server program on Ubuntu and added a rule in IPTables to allow incoming connections from port 5004. I started the server on Ubuntu and I tried to connect to the server using the client above on my macOS. The connection went through and the data exchange finished successfully.

Now to the problem. I installed Docker on my virtualized Ubuntu. Docker itself uses another version of Ubuntu 14.04. What I want is to run the server inside the Dockrized version of Ubuntu, so I wrote this Dockerfile:

```
FROM bamos/ubuntu-opencv-dlib-torch:ubuntu_14.04-opencv_2.4.11-dlib_19.0-torch_2016.07.12

ADD . /root

EXPOSE 5004

CMD ["python2", "/root/server.py"]
```

I build it using this command: `sudo docker build -t boring91/mock` and it was built successfully. I ran the Docker container using this command: `sudo docker run -p 5004:5004 -t boring91/mock` and it showed that it is started listening on port 5004. When I tried to connect to it using my client on my macOS, the socket connected but no data exchange happened. Same thing happens when I run the client on the virtualized Ubuntu. Can anyonw tell me whats the issue here?

Comment: Hold off on all the docker stuff for now. If you run everything locally on OS X, does your server work as expected?

Comment: @tangrs Yes, if I run the server as well as the client on macOS everything works as expected